# RewriteRule unexpectedly return 301

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm lost, I spent hours into this simple issue and can't figure what I'm doing wrong here.

This works as expected:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+/)$ index.php?eins=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&zwei=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

and rewrites this request: https://domain.tld/asdf/asdf/ **internally**
to https://domain.tld/index.php?eins=asdf&zwei=asdf
so far so good everything as expected.

But if I add this additional 2nd rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+/)$ index.php?eins=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&zwei=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Apache responds to the same request https://domain.tld/asdf/asdf/ with 301 to redirect to https://domain.tld/index.php/?eins=asdf&&zwei=asdghi/

I expected The first RewriteRule should be the L = Last one, but why is it redirecting? Actually I would like to achieve a 301 redirect **only** if a trailing slash is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) `L|last`,

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.

If you just want to add the trailing slash only for directory, you could try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If I add exactly your code only, it's not adding any slashes. I guess it's because the first line, related to the documentation, verifies if the directory exists. Which is not the case for me. But even without the first line it doesn't add a trailing slash but redirects to the absolute path from disk.

Comment: you should add `RewriteBase /`